# How to join 3 tables by a single sql query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 3 tables.

```
Table1: Group_Code, Group_Name,companyID;(PK: Group_Code)
Table2: PartyID,GroupID,companyID;(FK: GroupID, PK:PartyID)
Table3: VendorID, companyID;(FK:VendorID)
```

I want to fetch `Group_Name` from *Table1* for all *VendorID* of *Table3*. How can I do this?

here i write a code. But it shows `"Syntex error in FROM clause."` My database is in ms access.

```
select Group_Name from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.Group_Code= Table2.GroupID
join Table3 on Table2.PartyID=Table3.VendorID
```

Comment: `Table1 .Group_Code` Why the spaces?

Comment: sorry. this spaces is for typing mistake. I edit the question. Still shows the same error

Comment: && it's not syntex it's SYNTAX error

Answer (score 1):

```
select Group_Name from Table1 
join Table2 on Table1.Group_Code = Table2.GroupID 
join Table3 on Table2.PartyID = Table3.VendorID
```

Answer (score 1):

try this !!!

```
SELECT table1.group_name FROM (table1
     INNER JOIN ON table1.group_code=table2.groupid)
        INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.partyid=table3.vendorid

    GROUP BY    table1.group_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.group_name FROM table1 join table2 
                   ON table1.group_code=table2.groupid
                       join table3 ON table2.partyid=table3.vendorid

error becoz you didnt take the group name DB instance ?
```

Comment: :: Same error. Syntex error in FROM clause. My database in in MS ACCESS not in Sql server

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this :

```
select Table1.Group_Name, Table3.VendorID from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.Group_Code= Table2.GroupID join Table3 on Table2.PartyID =Table3.VendorID
```

If you are data has been stored in proper relationship. the query should get you going. :)

Comment: :: I make proper relationship. But it shows "Syntex error in FROM clause." My database is in access

Answer (score 0):

use this code for question,

```
Select Table1.Group_Name  from ((Table1
left join Table2 on Table1.Group_Code=Table2.GroupID)
left join Table3 on Table2.PartyID=Table3.VendorID)
```